# Heroku compiling assets that are locally pre-compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

We're precompiling our assets locally before pushing to Heroku -- so there's a load of files in public/assets that for the most part Heroku is using in production -- we're seeing asset compiliation notes in the log of 0ms. However, we're getting timeout errors when Heroku gets to `javascript_include_tag "application"` in our layout header and tries to recompile all the js all over again.

Is this meant to happen? How can we get Heroku to use only the locally-compiled assets and not keep spending 50s compiling assets again? Scaling up dynos does help, but that's not really addressing the root cause.

*// edit to explain how we're using the asset pipeline //*

We have a file in app/assets/javascript called application.js -- this is the manifest file that refers to all the javascript we need to be loaded. Here's a snippet:

```
//= require js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min
//= require js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min
//= require js/libs/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min
//= require js/libs/less-1.3.0.min
//= require js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min
```

There are 55 lines in this file.

We then use `javascript_include_tag "application"` in app/views/layouts/application.html.haml to call that manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways of using Rails asset pipeline on Heroku, and as you don't give us much details on implementation, the only thing I can recommend is reading this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

If you update the question with precise details of implementation I could try to be more helpful.

Comment: Did you push the public/assets folder to Git (including the manifest.yml)?

Comment: Yes indeed, and when we push to Heroku it's being identified.

Comment: So you confirm you have the message from Heroku : "Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally"? If yes, and it still re-compiles the assets, it is probably a bug in their system.

Comment: Ooh, that's quite exciting. Yes, I get that exact message.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **config/environments/production.rb** settings:

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```